# AJAX not rendering partial

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a view called `events\new.html.erb`which holds a collection select of other users. I want to make it so that every time the user selects a different name in the collection select, a `<div id="colleaguecal"></div>` is filled with the selected user's `Calendar` which holds their personal `Events`. However, I can't seem to get the partial `calendars\_showColleague.html.erb` which holds the calendar I want to render, to actually appear when the collection select is changed...

```
#events\new.html.erb

<%= f.collection_select :id,
                                Customer.where(business_id: current_customer.business_id),
                                :id,
                                :full_name,
                                { prompt: 'Select' },
                                { id: "colleageselect", onChange: "renderColCal(this)" } %>
```

```
#application.js
function renderColCal(select){

    var colleagueID = select.value ; //this variable is sent to Ruby for the database query to find the selected user
    $(document).on("change", "select#id", function(e){

            $.get("customers/"+ +$(this).val() + "/calendars/1");
        }
    );

}
```

..

```
#routes.rb
post 'calendars_controller/calendarChange', to: 'calendars_controller#calendarChange'
```

Then I am taking the javascript var `colleagueID` and using it in my `Calendars_controller#calendarChange`:

```
#calendars_controller.rb
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js, :html


  def new
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)

  end

  def create
    @calendar = Calendar.new(calendar_params)
  end

private
  def calendar_params
    params.require(:customer_id)
  end


  def show
    @calendar = current_customer.calendar
    @events = @calendar.events
  end

  def calendarChange
    colleagueID = params[:colleagueID] #the JS var is taken in here and then used to find the user in the database
    @colleague = Customer.where(id: :colleagueID)

    @colcalendar = @colleague.calendar
    @events = @colleague.calendar.events #the specific events that I want to render to the '_showColleague.html.erb' template

  end

end
```

I need to render the partial `calendars\_showColleague.html.erb` within `events\new.html.erb` where `_showColleague` is passed the `@events` and `@colcalendar` variables created in calendars#calendarChange. Before a customer has interacted with the collection_select, there should be nothing there, then once they have selected another customer, the selected customer's calendar (_showColleague) should appear below. How would I do this?

I was told to do this yesterday but it is not rendering anything:

```
#app/views/calendars/new.js.erb
$(".element").html("<%=j render 'calendars/_showColleague' %>");
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Refer this, note that you need not give the _(underscore) while rendering partials.

```
  $('.element').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'calendars/showColleague') %>");
```